# How to extract part of compressed file from tar archive

Tags: tar, hexdump

Given an archive `compressed.tar` containing files `file1` and `file2`, I know I can extract a single file like so: `tar xf compressed.tar file1`. However, if `file1` is a large file and I'm only interested in getting a hexdump of the first 8 bytes of the file, is there any way to extract just the first 8 bytes of the file instead of the whole thing?